# Hibernate retrieving list from onetomany

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I managed (as you can see in older posts from me) to insert a onetomany relation through hibernate. My two entity classes look like following:

Project.java:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id; 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="project")
    @OrderColumn(name = "project_index")
    List<Application> applications;
....
```

Application.java (which is a  child of project. One project can have many applications, but one application belongs to just one project)

```
@Entity
public class Application {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
...
```

So far, insertion of data works well. But getting data out of my database is the problem. I tried two ways:

---

**Way 1:** I retrieve a Project and try to get Applications out of the list attribute. But unfortunately Application entities are in a 'storedSnapshot', which seems pretty wrong to me. Here is a screenshot from my debug screen:

[image]

**Actually that way works! I did some mistakes somewhere else...**

---

**Way 2:** I try to retrieve a list of all applications via sql query:

```
public List<Application> getApplications(int project_id) {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  List<Application> applications = session.createQuery("from Application a where a.project_id=" + project_id + " ").list();
  return applications;
 }
```

..which throws strange exception -.-

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: project_id of: `de..common.entities.Application [from de..common.entities.Application a where a.project_id=1 ]`

**Problem with way 2 is that that I mix up SQL and HQL.**

---

A little help for a hibernate beginner would be great :-)
Cheers..

Comment: Explain what exactly is wrong with storedSnapshot?

Comment: @Bozho: what bag are u talking about

Comment: the one from your debug screenshot ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to access the applications by simply:

```
List<Application> applications = project.getApplications();
```

`PersistentBag` is implementing `java.util.List` so you should not care of its internals.

You will just need an open session to do that, otherwise a `LazyInitializationException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

> I try to retrieve a list of all applications via sql query (...) which throws strange exception

The exception is not strange and is exactly telling you what is wrong: `Application` doesn't have any `project_id` property, which is true (`project_id` is a database column).

Your query is not a **SQL** query, it's a **JPQL** query. JPQL queries are performed against **entities** (objects) and their associations. So you need to think object and associations.

In your case, (assuming you don't already have a `Project` instance but only a project `id`), you could do something like this:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM Application a WHERE a.project.id = :id");
q.setParameter("id", project_id);
List<Application> applications = (List<Application>) q.list();
```

Comment: Not if you are a beginner with all the frameworks and languages ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For way 1: I don't know about StoredSnapshot, but try setting the FetchType for your applications List to "EAGER". Maybe that would fix it.

For way 2: You are creating a query on your datamodel and not so much on your database. So the fields should be the fields in your java mapping. In this case:

```
List applications = session.createQuery("from Application a where a.project=" + project).list();
```

Note that the parameter you are passing to your function should be of type Project and not of type int.

Also, by using a named query you could do this:

```
 @NamedQuery(name="projectById",
             query="SELECT p FROM Project p"
                  + " LEFT JOIN FETCH applications"
            )
```

Comment: Okay thank you I gonna try that. Seems like I confused SQL with HQL